# go test unreproducible output from VS code to terminal

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Having the go extension in VScode, benchmarking a method is a matter of clicking on `[run benchmark]` and immediately you have the output of it in a vscode console followed by the command that ran plus the output:

```
Running tool: /usr/local/bin/go test -benchmem -run=^$ github.com/zyxan/benchmarks -bench ^BenchmarkRandomStringGeneration2$

goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/zyxan/benchmarks
BenchmarkRandomStringGeneration2-4      10000000           147 ns/op          80 B/op          3 allocs/op
PASS
ok      github.com/zyxan/benchmarks 1.654s
Success: Benchmarks passed.
```

Now if I want to reproduce such command on my terminal I literally just copy it

`/usr/local/bin/go test -benchmem -run=^$ github.com/zyxan/benchmarks -bench ^BenchmarkRandomStringGeneration2$`

Paste it on my terminal session results in the following output:

```
❯ /usr/local/bin/go test -benchmem -run=^$ github.com/zyxan/benchmarks -bench ^BenchmarkRandomStringGeneration2$
zsh: no matches found: -run=^$
```

Why is that discrepancy caused?

Comment: That's because your shell parses `-run=^$` somehow. Try `-run='^$'`.

Comment: Common is also -run=XXX

Comment: @Peter *sigh* so it all comes down to my shell, what a fail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using vs-code then you can use vs-code terminal provided by same to run the command and it will show the output of benchmark using the same command. It will parse the command.

```
go test -benchmem -run=^$ github.com/zyxan/benchmarks -bench ^BenchmarkParsingJSON$
```

Above command is used in vs-code terminal installed on windows.

As @Peter suggested on linux terminal you should parse the shell command using single inverted commas as

```
go test -benchmem -run='^$' github.com/zyxan/benchmarks -bench '^BenchmarkRandomStringGeneration2$'
```

Inside `-run` flag you need to pass the regex flag.

Comment: This is not completely valid as the VScode terminal session just opens a session on my zsh shell, so the problem still persists. But as Peter didn't provide an answer I'll flag this as answered for future generations

Comment: @AlexUnger I have tried it using git bash with my code. and It was working fine. And bash works like linux terminal. and -run flag consists of regex so you can provide it and use it according to your reuirement. Also -bench flag will also consists of regex so you can use `.` if you are in current working directory